Why receiving TCP network packets require more memory bandwidth and CPU utilization than transmitting packets?
I am analyzing an ARM system with Linux kernel 5.15 running. I am running iperf3 to measure the network throughput between two ARM systems.
Note that these are simulated systems and are loosely modeled after a real system.
I am seeing around 50% less throughput for receiving than transmitting.
When I tried to analyze the root cause, I noticed that RX has much more memory traffic than TX.
What is the reason behind this additional memory traffic?
Does the kernel perform additional memory copying for RX than for TX?
I would appreciate any help in understanding this behavior.
Update with more specific setup details:
I am using the gem5 hardware simulator (https://www.gem5.org/) to simulate two ARM-based systems.
Each has 8 cores (4 out-of-order and 4 in-order) that simulate an ARM bigLITTLE configuration.
Each system has a simulated NIC (Intel 8254x NIC model that works with e1000 Linux kernel driver).
NICs in two systems are connected with each other through a simulated switch.
I want to benchmark the RX and TX TCP network throughput between the two systems using iperf3 with the Linux kernel networking stack and I did not configure the driver to coalesce interrupts (will this improve performance for RX?). When running an instance of the iperf3 client or server, I use taskset to set the CPU affinity to a single core, but I do not set the interrupt affinity.
In my setup, I assume the Intel 8254x NIC model is close enough to a real NIC in functionality (maybe this is the issue). In a real NIC using the kernel networking stack, is there a reason for the kernel to do more work for RX than TX?

what will depend on your (emulated?) network hardware, what specifically you benchmark using iperf3 and whether you configured your kernel's network driver to coalesce interrupts, how the virtualizer and the kernel interact etc. You will need to tell us a lot more about what your stack looks like. Also, make sure you're actually benchmarking something relevant to your application; if this should model real-world networking throughput, then the real-world networking hardware plays a very relevant role that can't be "simulated".

@MarcusMüller thanks for the response, I updated the question with more specific setup details.

wait, this isn't even paravirtualization, but complete hardware virtualization? is your host at least a modern ARM, so that emulation and interrupts are not purely software virtualized? If not, then your benchmark really benchmarks nothing. It's really a bit of a strange idea to simulate a 20 year old intel NIC connected to a modern Arm bigLITTLE platform.

(in other words, the cost of getting the data in and out of your VMs, simulating hardware events etc by your virtualizer is probably higher than the cost of the network stack in the VM. You're not measuring real hardware performance, you're effectively measuring virtualizer properties, choosing a definitiely not optimized virtualized network interface.)

I should have been clear, I am not virtualizing the system and there are no VMs. Unlike QEMU, I am simulating the whole system including networking devices. NICs are not connected to a host system, the whole simulation is self-contained. While simulating a 20-year-old NIC is a concern (gem5 does not have any modern NIC models), my question was more about how the kernel networking stack handles receiving network packets, and whether receiving packets requires more data copying than transmitting a packet (without being specific to a platform or device).

OK, but that still 100% depends on the hardware, the kernel driver, and how you configure offloading, how the load is related to interrupt load and so on. That's why you can still sell new network cards in 2024 – they get better at taking load of the CPU/kernel. That's why it doesn't really matter whether your card is simulated or real – it's still behaving like a model of a 20 year old card, and not at all like a modern high-performance network card. For example, with my oooold Mellanox 10GBase PCIe card, I get similar throughput as with my newer one – but only for large packets, and at

higher peak single-core load. Better scatter gather list buffers, drivers that support more modern features of Linux, improved ability to handle larger and different regions of DMA targets, different "virtualized functions" that can filter things on the card itself, all that really makes a difference when we talk about a thing that's worth benchmarking.

I don't know how "deeply" you simulate your system's architecture, but especially for network cards that work at speeds close to saturation of the PCI bus (and Gigabit Ethernet exceeds the classical 32 bit PCI bandwidth), if your simulation is true to the real PCI bus, simulating a PCI card is a really bad choice – your bus controller needs to assign the PCI bus bandwidth to it all the time, but can't do so, so that you get cascading problems with packets waiting long to be DMA'd from the card, and so on. I don't know whether your simulator incorporates the local bus architecture – but it

probably does, considering that it claims it's designed to be used for designing local bus systems – and if does, using a PCI device (or PCI-X device) instead of a PCIe card just becomes a significant bottleneck, which completely breaks comparability with modern systems. PCIe is different – for good reason! PCI (and PCI-X) always suffered from the half-duplex data transfer, and the effective latency on modern PCIe systems is simply lower (due to lack of IRQ sharing) in practice.

I will look into the bus architecture and how well it simulates the PCI host, and also check whether the bus is the bottleneck for RX. Thank you very much for your time and insights!

again, even if it isn't: it just makes no sense to simulate a modern Arm architecture with a 20 year old PCI network card and then make statements on performance.
